# NSPopUpButton Enable vs Disable

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, appkit

I am building an app that has two NSPopUpButtons as part if the view. The 1st one is titled userChoice1 and the 2nd is userChoice2. I want userChoice2 to be disabled until the user makes a choice from userChoice1. How do I program the 2nd button to be disabled and then enable it. Is there a state property for the NSPopUpButton? I have searched the Apple documentation and API reference in Xcode and can't seem to find the property I need.

Thanks
Keith

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NSPopUPButton inherits from [NSControl](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSControl_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSControl/setEnabled:) which has a property

> setEnabled:

this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes, a classic mistake is to forget to check the superclass (and ancestors) for methods and properties that you're looking for.